Gremlin. How to use repeat() to find paths, and compare the relationship between adjacent array elements in until()
I have a graph like below.
g.addV('person').property('id', 'p1').property('name', 'Person 1').as('p1').
  addV('person').property('id', 'p2').property('name', 'Person 2').as('p2').
  addV('person').property('id', 'p3').property('name', 'Person 3').as('p3').
  
  addV('card').property('id', 'p1Card').property('number', '1111').as('p1Card').
  addV('card').property('id', 'p2Card').property('number', '2222').as('p2Card').
  addV('card').property('id', 'p3Card').property('number', '3333').as('p3Card').
  addV('card').property('id', 'p4Card').property('number', '4444').as('p4Card').
  
  addE('deposit').from('p1').to('p1Card').property('id', 'dep1').property('time', 1001).property('amt', 15000).
  
  addE('transfer').from('p1Card').to('p2Card').property('id', 'trans1').property('time', 1120).property('amt', 5000).
  addE('transfer').from('p2Card').to('p3Card').property('id', 'trans2').property('time', 1533).property('amt', 15000).
  addE('transfer').from('p3Card').to('p4Card').property('id', 'trans3').property('time', 2200).property('amt', 15000).
  
  addE('withdraw').from('p2Card').to('p2').property('id', 'with1').property('time', 1400).property('amt', 5000).
  addE('withdraw').from('p3Card').to('p3').property('id', 'with2').property('time', 2015).property('amt', 15000).
  iterate()

I want to find paths, in which

the transfer time of any two adjacent transfer edges is not greater than 50.
path is no longer than 10.
the time of edge is not greater than 4000.

I have try the query.
g.V().has('card', 'id', 'p1Card').as('start').repeat(
    outE('transfer', 'withdraw').as('e').inV().as('dst')
    .sideEffect(store('times').by('e.time'))
)
.until(
    __.loops().is(gte(10))
    .or().not(__.select('e').by('time').is(lte(4000)))
    .or(
        __.select('times').count(local).is(gte(2))
        .and().select('times').tail(2).unfold().math('it[1] - it[0]').is(gt(50))
    )
)
.emit(__.not(outE()))
.path().by('id')
.fold()
.next()

However the condition "transfer time of any two adjacent transfer edges is not greater than 50" has no effect.
If use 50, I want get no answer, however, this condition doesn't work, and the result hasn't changed after deleting the condition.
I have no more idea about how to describe it in Gremlin.
